# Selecting A Random Item From An Array iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, random

I'm trying to use the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo when the user have picked a photo. When they have picked the photo, I want to generate an item from an array to a UILabel, just like this:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",@"test3",@"test4",@"test5",@"test6", nil];

    int numberOfObjects = self.yourArrayOfStrings.count;

    NSInteger randomNumberInRange = arc4random() % numberOfObjects;

    NSString *randomText = [myArray objectAtIndex:randomNumberInRange];

    self->_label.text = randomText;
}
```

But I get the error: "Property 'yourArrayOfStrings' not found on object of type 'FDViewController *'" on the line: "int numberOfObjects = self.yourArrayOfStrings.count;".

I don't know what I should replace yourArrayOfStrings with. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you declare "yourArrayOfString" in the header file?

@interface FDViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *yourArrayOfString;
}

Comment: You should use `arc4random_uniform(NUMBER)` rather than `arc4random() % NUMBER` (which results in a non-uniform distribution for most values of `NUMBER`)!

Answer (score 2):

`NSInteger randomNumberInRange = arc4random() % [myArray count];`

Answer (score 1):

you should create **property for  yourArrayOfStrings** object if you want to refer it as

self. yourArrayOfStrings **other wise replace  yourArrayOfStrings with this
 _yourArrayOfStrings.**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some ready to use libraries like:

https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/random-utils